# Car animation from left to right and then hide car image

Tags: html, css

I need to make an animation of a moving car from left to right and then hide the picture and another one of the same, but from right to left.
Can someone help me with this?

This is my code for now:

```css
.car-movement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: run;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes run {
    0% {
        left: 0;
     }
    50% {
        left: calc(100% - 100px);
     }
    100% {
        left: 0;
     }
}
```

```html
<img class="car-movement" src="/assets/img/1car.svg" alt="car">
```

Comment: Hey, not really related to the question, but you should be using regular `@keyframes` and `animation` w/o the vendor prefixes.  Those are only supported by browsers using webkit as their renderer.  If you still do want the prefixes for properties that are required for more support, I advise you look into autoprefixer with post css.

Comment: okay, thanks) @sno2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the image in a div that has overflow.

Animate over `transform: rotateY` and `left`.

I used a div with a car emoticon, instead of an image.

```css
.car-movement {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

.car-movement > .car {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: linear infinite;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}


@keyframes run {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    left: -100px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    left: 100%;
  }
  51% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    left: calc(100% + 100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    left: -100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="car-movement">
  <div class="car"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, but how i can use position: absolute to use top rule for image?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that question? Because as the answer shows, you don't need absolute position on the car element (may it be image or div), only relative. What do you mean with "top rule"?

Comment: your solution suits me, but the car is not located well

Comment: Add the road as a background? What you're asking for is not framed in the original question.

Comment: yes, i need road as a backgorund, i forgot to mention it in my question

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want that car would ride from left to right and hide on the right side of the window?
Then you should edit this code part:

```css
      0% {
         left: -100px;
      }
      50% {
         left: calc(100% - 100px);
      }
```

Instead of 100px write car image length.
Also before all code, you should write this for the body:

```css
       body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.car-movement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: run;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes run {
     0% {
      left: 0;
     }
     48% {
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
     }
     50% { 
      left: calc(100% - 100px);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
     }
     98% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
     }
     100% {
     left: 0;    
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     }
}
```

```html
    <img class="car-movement" src="/assets/img/1car.svg" alt="car">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your keyframes a couple of intermediate steps you can not only get the car going from left to right and back again but you can get it to turn round before doing the right to left bit.

Obviously you need to put in your car svg image to get the full effect.

```css
.car-movement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 0;
  animation: linear infinite;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes run {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  50.5% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translate(0);
  }
  99.5% {
    left: 0;
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="car-movement" src="/assets/img/1car.svg" alt="car">
```